# Параметризированный запрос

Tags: delphi, sql

Можно ли создать в Delphi параметризированный SQL-запрос CREATE TABLE? Если можно, то как?
код такого типа не исполняется:

```
datamodule3.SQLQuery1.SQL.Text:='Create Table :dept_no';
datamodule3.SQLQuery1.ParamByName('dept_no').AsString:='asd55';
try
datamodule3.SQLQuery1.Open()
except
end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В операторе create table должны быть специфицированы столбцы. Ну, если это не PostgreSQL.
Иначе, запрос хотя бы должен быть таким:

```
Create Table asd55()
```

Comment: К величайшему сожалению, это не помогло. Он просто ругается на скобку. Код запроса я попробовал изменить на такой:

    datamodule3.SQLQuery1.SQL.Clear;
    fldValue := 'qweff';
    aa:='Create Table %s';
    datamodule3.SQLQuery1.SQL.Add(Format(aa,[fldValue]));
    try
    datamodule3.SQLQuery1.Open();
    except
    end;

Но на этот код говорит "неожиданный конец команды"

Comment: > Он просто ругается на скобку. 
Значит это не PostgreSQL. :-) Тогда нужно столбцы задавать.

Comment: Нет :(
Удаление скобки не помогло.

Comment: @Tyler ,Чушь несете..

1)Не **open**, а ***ExecSql*** надо сделать.

2)Столбцы указывайте, правильные.

Comment: > Нет :( Удаление скобки не помогло.

Я вам одно говорю - нужно добавить спецификации столбцов (хотя бы одного) в оператор create table, а вы мне другое.

Comment: @msi: приведите же пример, может, ТС не знает, как именно задавать столбцы. Я, например, на знаю :)

Comment: @vladD: например:
create table t(col1 int, col2 char(10));

Comment: @msi: спасибо от имени ТС!

Answer (score 2):

А вариант с фиксированным `CREATE TABLE` с одним столбцом `ID`, и в последствии `ALTER TABLE` и добавляйте нужные Вам столбцы сколько угодно, не подходит?

Comment: @Grizil, подходит конечно.

 Тут просто понимаете,зависит от фантазий разраба (насчет о каком СУБД идет речь молчу,об этом надо спросить автора ТЗ). 

Можно и вызвать какую нить ХП и передать просто название таблицы(количество столбцов,название столбцов или по дефолту создавать), изменить структуру как вы сказали, и т.д.

Comment: Кстати с хранимой процедурой вполне себе удобный вариант если есть надобность в таком создании таблиц.

А вообще меня не покидает ощущение что мы микроскопом гвозди забить пытаемся... Не думаю что принципиально задать параметризованно структуру таблицы именно на CREATE TABLE. Скорее нужно просто задать структуру таблицы, а одна или две строчки будут выполнятся - эти тонкости вряд ли сильно волнуют человека у которого в коде 

    datamodule3.SQLQuery1 

встречается.. Хотя возможно я излишне придирчив.